# Changing color for different elements on the entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I'd like to have a color-switch buttons on my page. So by clicking it the exact color would be changed to other. The problem is that the color is used for backgrounds, borders, and font-colors. Is' there a way to detect with jquery the exact color and change it everywhere to other one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there something you've tried before, or at least a minimal snippet we can work with?

Comment: Sorry, but I really see no need for putting my code.
I have one solution by giving classes (red/green/blue) and by clicking color-button I change my css.
But I am just wandering if there is a way to target the exact #color on the entire page and then change it?

Comment: There is a reason to put your code here. It enables users to see what you've tried thus far and help get the desired effect working. Also I'm not 100% sure on what you mean with your question. Are you saying you want a button that a user can click that will change the style of the entire site theme?

Answer (score 0):

Ok had to guess a lilttle with what you wanted, but since you want to change specific things all at once. I recommend you add a class to the elements you know you want to change. For example, you could use `class = "colorChange"` and add two buttons. One button to change everything to blue, and the other to red.

HTML buttons:

```
<button id="blue">BLUE</button>
<button id="red">RED</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#blue').on('click', function () {
    $('.colorChange').css({
        'background-color': 'blue',
        'color': 'blue'
    });
});

$('#red').on('click', function () {
    $('.colorChange').css({
        'background-color': 'red',
        'color': 'red'
    });
});
```

Here is a lil demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/03k3bd5t/2/)

To check to see what the current color is you can do. `$('.colorChange').css('background-color');` but this will give you the rbg code. (For example, rbg(1, 1, 1))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a silly piece of code to change the color of every *black* element of your page:

```
var sourceColors = ["black", "#000000", "#000", "rgb(0,0,0)"];
var targetColor = "orange";
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
for (var i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; i++) {
    var e = elements[i];
    if (sourceColors.indexOf(e.style.color)) {
        e.style.color = targetColor;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is what you want and it is not a ver fast method, but it works.

Comment: I really hope your joking.  ;-)